# Canvas.drawArc() doesn't draw anything

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I'm trying to draw an arc to overlay on top of some part of an existing circle. Both of my circles draw perfectly fine, but neither my drawArc() call or my drawRect() call seem to do anything. The app does not crash, there is no exception. It just fails silently.

onDraw() code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    int size = (width > height) ? height : width;

    float cx = width / 2;
    float cy = height / 2;
    float radius = size / 2;

    float left = cx - radius;
    float right = cx + radius;
    float top = cy - radius;
    float bottom = cy + radius;

    RectF rect = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
    RectF rect2 = new RectF(canvas.getClipBounds());

    Log.d("MyTag", "Left: " + rect.left + "Right: " + rect.right + "Top: " + rect.top + "Bottom: " + rect.bottom);
    Log.d("MyTag", "Left: " + rect2.left + "Right: " + rect2.right + "Top: " + rect2.top + "Bottom: "
            + rect2.bottom);

    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, circleRing);//Works
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius - barWidth, innerColor);//Works
    canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, angle, true, circleColor);//Doesn't work
    canvas.drawRect(rect, circleColor);//Doesn't work

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

I have confirmed that my `circleColor` Paint is properly setup, and that `angle` is a valid value for an arc.

My paints are setup as follows in a {} block so that all constructors use it:

```
{
    circleColor = new Paint();
    innerColor = new Paint();
    circleRing = new Paint();

    circleColor.setColor(color.holo_blue_light);
    innerColor.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    circleRing.setColor(Color.GRAY);

    circleColor.setAntiAlias(true);
    innerColor.setAntiAlias(true);
    circleRing.setAntiAlias(true);

    circleColor.setStrokeWidth(50);
    innerColor.setStrokeWidth(5);
    circleRing.setStrokeWidth(5);

    circleColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
}
```

What I have tried:

- Hardcoding coordinates
- Using the paints used by the circles
- Having only the drawArc() call present and commenting out the rest of the draws
- Disabling hardware acceleration

The Logcat shows that my RectF has valid points, just top and bottom scaled to form a square:

```
01-25 13:33:39.877: D/MyTag(21612): Left: 0.0 Right: 720.0 Top: 159.0 Bottom: 879.0 //Mine
01-25 13:33:39.877: D/MyTag(21612): Left: 0.0 Right: 720.0 Top: 0.0 Bottom: 1038.0 //Canvas'
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Comment: o/ What view are you overriding? And what's the last drawRect supposed to do? Won't that just paint over everything? I just tried it with some generic Paint objects and colors, and using the first two drawCircle and the drawArc call seems to work as expected on my Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: @kcoppock Heya :P. The last drawRect I added only for debugging purposes. I still see both my circles, and no rectangle or arc. I'm directly extending the base android.view.View class. I'm also on a Galaxy Nexus, but the draw arc call is simple ignored for me.

Comment: Also tried it on a Nexus 7. Same lack of arc.

Comment: Huh. Just curious, how *are* your Paints set up? Here's the exact code I used: http://pastie.org/5853922

Comment: @kcoppock Edited with paints. I also found the solution. Adding an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the line

```
circleColor.setColor(color.holo_blue_light);
```

While the Android SDK defines this as:

> A light Holo shade of blue
>
> Constant Value: 17170450 (0x01060012)

It doesn't seem to be a valid color as far as my Canvas is concerned (note that this was added in API 14, and I'm testing on Android 4.2 so it should be available to me). However, changing it to use a more... normal color works fine:

```
circleColor.setColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: Ah, yeah you'd have to get that through Resources, like `circleColor.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light));`

Comment: @kcoppock That's exactly what I ended up doing :-) Thanks for the help!